# Atlas-ing going wrong

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

(I'm a complete newbie so pardon me if I sound stupid)

I've been trying to export a model using the CATS plugin but I'm stuck at atlas-ing, every time I try to save an atlas, the image I posted happens.

I'm guessing this could be a common problem so I went here. Any help, leads, advice, anything, will go a long way. Thank you!

[image: Example of what happens]

Comment: Have you changed the mesh UVs ?

Comment: @Gorgious I'm sorry but how do I do that exactly? I've posted an image below.
I've gone into the UV editor but what do I exactly do here? I'm really sorry if I'm wasting your time.

https://imgur.com/a/9odxsKW